# Selecting an option tag which is exactly equal to the search text

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, cascadingdropdown

I have coded for setting a drop down menu's option to a specific value when the text is known but I have encountered a problem. The following code is what I use:

`$('#dropDownId option:contains("' + searchText + '")').prop('selected', true).change();`

The `contains` part of the code won't serve the purpose of the code since the drop down has two options which are sub strings of one another.

Is there a way where I could specify that I want the exact match of the given `searchText`??

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364298/make-jquerys-contains-select-only-exact-string

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. What should I do now? Delete this question?