# jQuery selector for searching the exact same string

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which search for any dialogs which contains the text `hello`.

```
var found = $('span.ui-dialog-title:contains("hello")');
```

I need the same kind of statement but the dialog title must be exactly `hello`. Something like:

```
var found = $('span.ui-dialog-title:equals("hello")');
```

Unfortunately `equals` does not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364298/make-jquerys-contains-select-only-exact-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `equals` selector. You need to use `.filter()` function instead.

```
$('span.ui-dialog-title').filter(function(){
  return $(this).text() === "hello";
});
```