# Find: Variable value not Matching

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

I'm using **this variable** to get one or more values matching to what I need.

```
var mail = $("#dat").contents().find("td:contains('" + name + "')" ).siblings("td:nth-child(2)").map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get();
```

My **data** look like this:

```
<tr><td> Name Second-Name </td><td>Email</td></tr>
<tr><td> Name Second-Name </td><td>Email 2</td></tr>
<tr><td> Name Second-Name Third-Name </td><td>Email 3</td></tr>
```

When I use `Name Second-Name` as `name` value, this variable returns `Email`, `Email 2` and `Email 3`, even with `Third-Name` inside the last table row. What I need is a variable that returns `Email` and `Email 2` only, ignoring the last row - where I have another name.

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: So basically `.find("td:contains('" + name + "'):not(:contains('" + other_name + "'))" )`

Comment: Are you looking for an [exact match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364298/make-jquerys-contains-select-only-exact-string) instead of a contains?

Comment: Thanks! No, adeneo, my data is more complicated than that, I don't have all `other_names` to use on my variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var name = " Name Second-Name ";
var mail = $('td').filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === name }).siblings("td:nth-child(2)").map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ksL6opd7

Comment: @ZecaNovaes Just noticed there's a space between `<td>` and `Name Second-Name` and `</td>`. If you put a space, try with `var name = " Name Second-Name "`;

Comment: Same problem here. I don't know why the only way to filter my data is using find:contain

Comment: Thanks! Working here!!