# Replace text issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check if the text exist and remove it. I need to find if the text exist and remove the parent items. For example If the the **With Name + Date** exist then remove :

```
<dt>Font</dt>
<dd>Arial </dd>
```

Another example if the **With Name + Date + Time** exist then remove:

```
<dt>Font</dt>
<dd>Comic Sans </dd>
```

My code:

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  if (jQuery('.item-options dd:contains("With Name")').length > 0)
  {
    var parent = jQuery('.item-options dd:contains("With Name")').parent('dl');
    jQuery(parent).find('dt:contains("Font")').html('');    
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="item-options">
  <dt>Radio test</dt>
  <dd>With Name </dd>
  <dt>Font</dt>
  <dd>no font selected </dd>
</dl>
<dl class="item-options">
  <dt>Radio test</dt>
  <dd>With Name + Date</dd>
  <dt>Font</dt>
  <dd>Arial </dd>
</dl>
<dl class="item-options">
  <dt>Radio test</dt>
  <dd>With Name + Date + Time</dd>
  <dt>Font</dt>
  <dd>Comic Sans </dd>
</dl>
```

My issue is because **With Name** exist in all and my javascript is apply to all. How I can make the javascript to search exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make jQuery's \`:contains()\` select only exact string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364298/make-jquerys-contains-select-only-exact-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [**`filter`**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function. The [**`contains`**](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector will not try to get an exact match, but, like the name says, a string that contains the desired text.

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  if (jQuery('.item-options dd').filter(function() {
    return jQuery(this).text() === "With Name";
  }).length > 0)
  {
    var parent = jQuery('.item-options dd:contains("With Name")').parent('dl');
    jQuery(parent).find('dt:contains("Font")').html('');    
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="item-options">
  <dt>Radio test</dt>
  <dd>With Name </dd>
  <dt>Font</dt>
  <dd>no font selected </dd>
</dl>
<dl class="item-options">
  <dt>Radio test</dt>
  <dd>With Name + Date</dd>
  <dt>Font</dt>
  <dd>Arial </dd>
</dl>
<dl class="item-options">
  <dt>Radio test</dt>
  <dd>With Name + Date + Time</dd>
  <dt>Font</dt>
  <dd>Comic Sans </dd>
</dl>
```

Looks ugly, but works.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364298/make-jquerys-contains-select-only-exact-string)

Comment: Hi phiter thank you so much, but I don't know why the code is not work.

Comment: Hi Phiter Fernandes can you tell what is wrong with this code and why Font text is not removed? I try it in my page too and is the same like here, if you press Run code snippet you will see that the Font is still there. Thank you

Comment: I will take a look at it.

Comment: thannk you so much

Comment: Phiter Fernandes I manage to make it work but this code will remove Font from everywhere, I need to be removed only in the item where exist just the text With Name simple.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the html architecture or otherwise remove whatever you want.i hope this will help you.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 if ($('.item-options dd:contains("With Name")').length > 0)
  { 
   var parent = $('.item-options');
   var children = $('.item-options').find("dd");
   $(children).each(function(i,e){
    if(~$(e).text().indexOf("With Name + Date + Time")){
     $(e).nextAll().remove();
    }
   else if(~$(e).text().indexOf("With Name + Date")){
     $(e).nextAll().remove();
    }
  });

 }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/3270/

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, but what happens if the With Name is not exist and there is only With Name + Date + Time? I try and if With Name is not exist is remove the script remove everything that contain With Name

Comment: Hi, can you tell me how I can remove only the text Font? in your code? instead this $(e).nextAll().remove(); I need to remove only text Font