# find the <a> tag by text of the href

Tags: jquery, href

I want to use jQuery to find a link and hide it . I want to search for the text of the link using jQuery. This doesn't work:

```
<a href="example.com/foo-bar">a website link</a>
```

```js
function replace_text() {
  var linkText = jQuery('a').text();
  var answer = linkText.replace('a website link', '');
}
replace_text();
```

Comment: use `a[href=^example.com]` learn more in https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364298/select-element-by-exact-match-of-its-content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To hide the element by it's text you could use the `:contains` selector, then `hide()`, like this:

```js
$('a:contains("a website link")').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="example.com/foo-bar">a website link</a>
```

Note that the above is a case-insensitive greedy match. If you want an *exact* match you can use `filter()`, like this:

```js
$('a').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() == 'a website link';
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="example.com/foo-bar">a website link</a>
```

Comment: $('a:contains("a website link")').hide(); works when i use the Chrome dev tools but not when i add it to my js file. Can the fact that !important is used have any effect here?

Comment: Nope. That sounds more like you aren't including your JS code at the right time. Make sure you execute the above code within a document ready handler, eg `$(function() { /* code here... */ });`

Comment: I did this. Could there be any other reason it doesn't work?

Comment: There's plenty, but hard to tell exactly without seeing a working example of your code. Try checking the console for errors

Comment: I added a console.log message and it appears in the dev tools for that page

Comment: to give the real example here: the page is https://www.apis.de/unternehmen/kontakt/map/ and the text i want to hide is 'Map by Fla-shop.com'

Comment: Right - you've got two issues here. Firstly, the issue is because that text is added after the page loads - hence the above code has no effect. You need to run the code when the map has fully loaded. Secondly, what you're doing is most likely illegal. You're trying to remove the link to the content creator. I suggest you pay for the full version of the software instead of trying to subvert their system.

Comment: Ok. I see, I hadn't thought of any legal issues. I will have to look into that further.