# use :not(selector) to hide elements with class not equal search parameter

Tags: jquery

The following line works.  When I typed ID 22 in my search field, it shows all rows containing 22, which include 2212, 8922...

```
$('#patientTable .ID:not(:contains("' + sID + '"))').parent().hide();
```

Now I want to hide all rows except the one with exact match. I tried the following code.  It returns nothing. Please help.

```
$('#patientTable .ID:not(sID)').parent().hide();
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of your table and a sample output of sID?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select element by exact match of its content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364298/select-element-by-exact-match-of-its-content)

Comment: You can't just include a variable in a string - you need to concatenate, just as you have in your first example. In this particular case, you can't exact-match using your proposed syntax, but consider it food-for-thought moving forward.

Comment: The sID is a unique key in the table.  There is no duplicates.  What syntax can I use for exact-match?

Comment: Check the link I post as possible duplicate