# Highlighting content in cell on input filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller

I use ASP.NET MVC5 & JQuery. Currently I have a table setup that is filled with values from a database. Two columns: Name & Explanation

I can filter through both columns by typing and all rows that have a value that contains the input will be shown. Because the explanations are quite lengthy I would like to highlight the exact matches in the values in the cells. Think of making them bold, curved or anything like that.

Is there any way I could do this using JQuery?

---

EDIT1:

Filtering itself works already. I would just like to see the following to happen:

input: *Book in t*

Cell value: *Today I am reading a **Book in t**he garden.*

The purpose of this would be to clarify where the value matches with your input.

Let me know if you have any more questions!

---

Input on which I filter:

```
<tr class="tableRow">
   <td><input type="search" class="form-control tableFilter"  placeholder="Filter..." /></
</tr>
```

Current JQuery that handles filtering:

```
//Table Filter based on input
$(".tableFilter").keyup(function () {
    //split the current value of searchInput
    var data = this.value.split(" ");
    //create a jquery object of the rows
    var jo = $(".table").find("tbody tr");
    if (this.value == "") {
        jo.show();
        return;
    }
    //hide all the rows
    jo.hide();

    //Filter the jquery object to get results.
    jo.filter(function (i, v) {
        var $t = $(this);
        var matched = true;
        for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
            if (data[d].match(/^\s*$/)) {
                continue;
            }
            var regex = new RegExp(data[d].toLowerCase());
            if ($t.text().toLowerCase().replace(/(manual|auto)/g, "").match(regex) === null) {
                matched = false;
            }
        }
        return matched;
    }).show();
})
```

Comment: Can You provide any code? Will be easier to help. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15364327/5962118) will be helpful.

Comment: Added code and some extra explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this. Instead of using regex I used here `indexOf` function to get to know if provided string exist in cell.

```js
//Table Filter based on input
$(".tableFilter").keyup(function() {

  var rows = $(".table").find("tbody tr");

  //Filter the jquery object to get results.
  if (this.value.length > 0) {
   //First hide all an remove class used to identify matched rows
    rows.removeClass("match").hide().filter(function() {
     var match = false;
     $(this).find("td.filter").each(function() {
        var indexOf = $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(".tableFilter").val().toLowerCase());
        //Check with indexOf if this row cell include search string
        if(indexOf !== -1) {
          match = true;
           return;
        } 
      });
     return match;
    }).addClass("match").show();
  } else {
   //If filter not provided show all 
    rows.removeClass("match").show().find("b").contents().unwrap();
  }

  highlight(this.value);
})

var highlight = function(string) {
  $(".table").find("tbody tr.match td.filter").each(function() {
  
   if($(this).text().indexOf(string) === -1)
     return;
  
    var matchStartIndex = $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(string.toLowerCase());
    var matchEndIndex = matchStartIndex + string.length - 1;

    var beforeMatch = $(this).text().slice(0, matchStartIndex);
    var matchText = $(this).text().slice(matchStartIndex, matchEndIndex + 1);
    var afterMatch = $(this).text().slice(matchEndIndex + 1);

    //Here set selected text to e.g. bold style
    $(this).html(beforeMatch + "<b>" + matchText + "</b>" + afterMatch);
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" class="form-control tableFilter" placeholder="Filter..." />
<table class="table" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr class="tableRow">
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="filter">test of tests</td>
      <td class="filter">second of tests</td>
      <td>Edit/Delete</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filter">book in the garden</td>
      <td class="filter">two books in the garden</td>
      <td>Edit/Delete</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filter">chain hell</td>
      <td class="filter">chain hell continues</td>
      <td>Edit/Delete</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes! This is what I intended to do! You're a champ!
One issue though is that the matching text it returns is not shown in table form anymore. Just a long string with highlighted bits, do you happen to know how I'd fix that?
Edit: I just fiddled around with it, and when I backspace my search value untill it is empty, every value in the name Collumn is replaced with a string made of the entire length of the search result string.

Comment: Now should be better. I was replacing whole tr than only single cell (td).

Comment: In your example there is only 1 collumn. In my case there is 1 input field filtering two collumns.
For some reason when a match happens in the 2nd collumn it gets automatically moved to the 1st. What makes that happen?

Comment: Yep because I wasn't considering more columns. Made some edits and now it will accept as many cols as You wish.

Comment: You're a champ! Fixed something in 45 minutes I've been struggling with all day!

Comment: One more question, there is actually a third collumn with icons to edit/delete the row. These change to the following after filtering:
"× Edit definition Name: Definition: Cancel Confirm". Is there a way to have them not affected by the filter? Or atleast not have the icons replaced by this text but have them reappear?

Comment: You can for example add special class for columns allowed to be filtered like I did in this example.

Comment: This worked great!
Could you help me out a bit more? Some entries in the table are clickable and will link to a page. When highlighting the link attribute disappears, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You mean when searching for text to highlight which is a link?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The link ability is removed upon highlighting. Also when completely removing the input in the input field, the last letter that was removed remains highlighted. I.e. when I search for: "Everest" and I remove that from the input field, all "E"'s in all cells remain highlighted. Sorry for asking so much of you :P