# Syntax to select element by exact match of it's content

Tags: jquery, filter, jquery-selectors

I'm having syntax issues when selecting elements by exact match of its content.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#scorecardId").change(function () {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#myTable tr").filter(function () {
            //filters by the 8th column scorecard
            $(this).toggle($(this).children(":eq(8)").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-responsive table-striped">
<tr>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>
        <a href="@Html.GetUrlAndRouteObject(Model.Sort, "change_date")">
            Change Date
            @Html.AddSortArrow(Model.Sort, "change_date")
        </a>
    </th>
    <th>
        Effective Date
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.type, new SelectList(Model.type), "-Type-", new { @id = "typeId" })
    </th>
    <th>
        Description
    </th>
    <th>
        Empid
    </th>
    <th>
        SSO
    </th>
    <th>
        Agent_Name
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.type, new SelectList(Model.scorecard), "-Scorecard-", new { @id = "scorecardId" })
    </th>
    <th>
        Load_Date
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.get_staff_changelog_results)
{
    <tbody id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "StaffChange", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "myform" }))
                {
                    @Html.Hidden("sso", item.SSO)
                    @Html.Hidden("name", item.Agent_Name)
                    <a href="javascript: submitForm();" class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></a>
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Change_Date)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Effective_Date)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Empid)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SSO)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Agent_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Scorecard)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Load_Date)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
}
```

The function above is finding any string that contains my input string. If I'm searching for **CAM**, the result output may include **CAM, CAM TOS, CAM FOO**, etc. When in reality, I **only** want **CAM** in my results. I understand my syntax isn't looking for this but this is where i'm having issues.

I found a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364298/select-element-by-exact-match-of-its-content) that explains what I'm looking for, but I can't get the correct syntax to work. I've tried the below, but doesn't seem to work:

```
$(this).toggle($(this).children(":eq(" + "8" + ")").text().toLowerCase() === value > -1)
```

What is the correct syntax to find an exact match?

Comment: if you want exact match, why not use `x.text().toLowerCase()==="cam"`?

Comment: `.indexOf(value) > -1` gives you `if contains` not the exact match

Comment: I tried $(this).toggle($(this).children(":eq(" + "8" + ")").text().toLowerCase()) === value   but that does not seem to work either.

Comment: Could you just share the HTML? Then it would be easy to solve your problem.

Comment: sure - I updated the question with the HTML

Comment: If you are using loop to print the `<tbody id="myTable">` You are going to have multiple `myTable` ids

Comment: Please simplify `":eq(" + "8" + ")"` to `":eq(8)"`  -- Hurts my eyes to see that.

Comment: ha - true. Updated...

Answer (score 0):

After taking the `<tbody>` tag out of the `for` loop.
Try this, though not much different from what you have tried.
Also console.log the two texts you are comparing to see if they are producing the expected texts.

```
$(this).toggle(($(this).children(":eq(8)").text().toLowerCase()) === value);
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately, that did not work. When I took the <tbody> tag out, It looks like I lose scope when I'm filtering. since I'm using the id of #myTable in my filter