# Select value in select by text when select have a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<select name="search[active]" class="form-control" placeholder="Active" />
    <option value="1">True</option>
    <option value="0">False</option>
</select>
```

And I want to select an option by value, for example, select True, for this I try whit the following code:

```
$('[name="search[active]"').text(True);
```

and

```
$('[name="search[active]"').val(True);
```

and not work.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector by value will be like :

```
$('[name="search[active]"] option[value=1]').text();
```

And the selector by text will use `:contains()` like :

```
$('[name="search[active]"] option:contains(True)').val();
```

```js
//Select By value
console.log($('[name="search[active]"] option[value=1]').text());
console.log($('[name="search[active]"] option[value=0]').text());

//Select By text
console.log($('[name="search[active]"] option:contains(True)').val());
console.log($('[name="search[active]"] option:contains(False)').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="search[active]" class="form-control" placeholder="Active">
  <option value="1">True</option>
  <option value="0">False</option>
</select>
```

Comment: how can select element by exact match?

Comment: Already answered here @eslop https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364298/select-element-by-exact-match-of-its-content