# How to search only for a specific span tag in a HTML list and not for all list items? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I have a problem with my category filter. 
I've created a dropdown selection with different categorys and a normal list with informations like title and category. If a user selects a option at example "IT" it shows all list items with the word "IT". Now the problem is that it filters for all words with "IT" in it but I want to search only for the tag "categoryname".

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".categoryselection").on("change", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myList li.list-choose span.kategorie, #myList li.list-choose").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
      $("span.categoryname").css({
        display: 'block',
        color: '#e60'
      })
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="categoryselection">
  <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Category</option>
  <option value="All categorys">All categorys</option>
  <option value="Economy">Economy</option>
  <option value="Politics">Politics</option>
  <option value="IT">IT</option>
</select>

<ul id="myList">
  <li class="list-choose">
    <input class="input-choose" type="checkbox" id="[ID]" />
    <label class="label-choose" for="[ID]">Magazine 1: test</label>
    <div class="subtitle">
      <span class="categoryname" style="display: none">Economy<span style="display: none">All categorys</span></span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-choose">
    <input class="input-choose" type="checkbox" id="[ID]" />
    <label class="label-choose" for="[ID]">Magazine 2: test 2</label>
    <div class="subtitle">
      <span class="categoryname" style="display: none">Politics<span style="display: none">All categorys</span></span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-choose">
    <input class="input-choose" type="checkbox" id="[ID]" />
    <label class="label-choose" for="[ID]">Magazine 2: test 3</label>
    <div class="subtitle">
      <span class="categoryname" style="display: none">Economy<span style="display: none">All categorys</span></span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-choose">
    <input class="input-choose" type="checkbox" id="[ID]" />
    <label class="label-choose" for="[ID]">Magazine 2: IT</label>
    <div class="subtitle">
      <span class="categoryname" style="display: none">No category<span style="display: none">All categorys</span></span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can see that it also searches for the name of the list items (If you choose the category "IT" it also displays "politics" because IT is inside this word - but this is not what I want :D). But I want that it only looks for the span tag in the class "categoryname".

Comment: Getting familiar with the basic [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) of the library you're working with is always useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several problems with your code:

- when faced to this kind of problem, you should learn how to debug, for example with `console.log`, to be sure your selections get what you want (remove comments to see them in action)
- You were using `filter` here for no reason. Filter returns an array that filters your base array depending if the argument function returns `true` or `false`. Use rather jQuery's `each` or plain JS `map`
- You can use `find` to select elements inside your first selection
- you get several categories tags in a string, if you want to isolate them, you have to use a separator (I choosed "|"). Then you can use `split` to transform the string into an array, and `indexOf` to check for the match:

Good luck!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".categoryselection").on("change", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myList li.list-choose span.kategorie, #myList li.list-choose").each(function() {
      //console.log($(this)); //will show the current element
      //console.log($(this).text()); //will show the current element's text
      $(this).toggle($(this).find(".categoryname").text().toLowerCase().split("|").indexOf(value) > -1);
      $("span.categoryname").css({
        display: 'block',
        color: '#e60'
      })
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="categoryselection">
  <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Category</option>
  <option value="All categorys">All categorys</option>
  <option value="Economy">Economy</option>
  <option value="Politics">Politics</option>
  <option value="IT">IT</option>
</select>

<ul id="myList">
  <li class="list-choose">
    <input class="input-choose" type="checkbox" id="[ID]" />
    <label class="label-choose" for="[ID]">Magazine 1: test</label>
    <div class="subtitle">
      <span class="categoryname" style="display: none">Economy<span style="display: none">|All categorys</span></span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-choose">
    <input class="input-choose" type="checkbox" id="[ID]" />
    <label class="label-choose" for="[ID]">Magazine 2: test 2</label>
    <div class="subtitle">
      <span class="categoryname" style="display: none">Politics<span style="display: none">|All categorys</span></span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-choose">
    <input class="input-choose" type="checkbox" id="[ID]" />
    <label class="label-choose" for="[ID]">Magazine 2: test 3</label>
    <div class="subtitle">
      <span class="categoryname" style="display: none">Economy<span style="display: none">|All categorys</span></span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-choose">
    <input class="input-choose" type="checkbox" id="[ID]" />
    <label class="label-choose" for="[ID]">Magazine 2: IT</label>
    <div class="subtitle">
      <span class="categoryname" style="display: none">No category<span style="display: none">|All categorys</span></span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In you case, you are using indexOf to find the first occurence, and not an exact matching.

As shown on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364298/select-element-by-exact-match-of-its-content), you've to use strict comparison.

In your script, replace :

```
 $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
```

By

```
if (value === $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase())
```