# Find exact match of td text content

Tags: javascript, jquery

This function loads HTML via AJAX and performs a search/scrape using `find()`. It works well if the server name is unique. However as per the example below, if I make a search for `server10` it will print out `server109 & amer` since it appears first in the HTML.

Is there a way I can use to find exact match and console log `server10 & apj`. Have tried various method but didn't work. Kindly suggest or provide example.

```js
function vm(vm_server) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://someurl.com',
    dataTpe: 'html',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
      var server_name = $(data).find("td:contains(" + vm_server + ")").text();
      var location = $(data).find('td:contains("' + server_name + '")').next().text();
      console.log(server_name)
      console.log(location)
    }
  });
}
```

someurl.html

```html
<tr>
  <td>server109</td>
  <td>amer</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>server10</td>
  <td>apj</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>server102</td>
  <td>apac</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>server105</th>
  <td>emea</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: do these answers help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364298/select-element-by-exact-match-of-its-content ?

Comment: `:contains` is a greedy match, as you've discovered. If you want an exact match, use `filter()`

Comment: Also note that your HTML is invalid; you have used `</th>` instead of `</td>`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you for fixing title & description. I have tried filter however didn't get any output. Could you share on how you would make it work?

Comment: It would be better if you updated the question to show what you tried so we can help you debug it

Comment: Also note that getting the text of an element you select by its text is entirely redundant (ie. the `server_name` variable)