# Replacing different links specific text with Font Awesome icons, is causing duplicates of the same icons

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to replace specific text within a link with Font Awesome Icons. I am able to do that, but the icons are all the same(as first one). Why is it showing duplicates and how do I fix it?

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://">FacebookIcon</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://">FacebookIconCircle</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://">FacebookIconSquare</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#main-header .widget.Header .header-widget .header-identity .header-title-tagline ul li a:contains("FacebookIcon")').html('<i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>');
$('#main-header .widget.Header .header-widget .header-identity .header-title-tagline ul li a:contains("FacebookIconCircle")').html('<i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>');
$('#main-header .widget.Header .header-widget .header-identity .header-title-tagline ul li a:contains("FacebookIconSquare")').html('<i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>');
```

Result:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Desired Result

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Every one of them contains `FacebookIcon`. Therefore at the first HTML replacement, every one of them is replaced with icons. Maybe you should check for equality rather than containment.

Comment: Yes, the solution here works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364298/select-element-by-exact-match-of-its-content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you might consider using [.filter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364298/select-element-by-exact-match-of-its-content) to further specify your selector, it might be better to consider using `.html()`. Using `.html()`, you can iterate through all your selected `<a>` elements. You can also make an object which maps icons names to font-awesome tags. For each anchor tag, you can get its text, and use that in the look-up for the object like so:

```js
const icons = {
  'FacebookIcon': '<i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>',
  'FacebookIconCircle': '<i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>',
  'FacebookIconSquare': '<i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>'
};

$('a').html(function() {
  return icons[$(this).text()];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://">FacebookIcon</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://">FacebookIconCircle</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://">FacebookIconSquare</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use this URL in your example to get the icons to appear: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css